# How do I use bash to compare 1000 files in sequential order - 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and so on

Tags: bash, for-loop, diff

I have about 1000 html files in a directory that are different versions of a webpage. Each is named by the date the page was modified - e.g. `20190104`, `20190105` - but there are occasional gaps, such as between `20190105` and `20190107`.

I know how to use diff to compare one file to the immediately subsequent version and save the differences to a third file, but I want a loop that will that for all 1000. The standard `for i in ./*` doesn't work because I need to reference multiple files inside the loop.

I suspect I need to turn the list of files into an array, and then have a for loop that references array elements n and n+1, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> elements n and n+1

No, don't think in the future - you don't know it. You know the past - iterate over `n-1` and `n`.

```
prev=  # empty previous filename
for cur in ./*; do
   if [[ -n "$prev" ]]; then    # if prev is Nonempty
        do_stuff "$prev" "$cur"
   fi
   prev=$cur
done
```

Comment: Oh, brilliant! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing by pairs:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

comparePairs() {
  while [ $# -gt 1 ]
  do
    printf 'Compare %s with %s.\n' "$1" "$2"
    shift
  done
}

comparePairs foo bar baz cuux
```

output:

```
Compare foo with bar.
Compare bar with baz.
Compare baz with cuux.
```

Now your diff pairs:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

diffPairs() {
  outputDir="$1"
  shift
  while [ $# -gt 1 ]
  do
    diff "$1" "$2" > "$outputDir/$1-$2.diff"
    shift
  done
}

# Use first argument as output directory
diffPairs "$@"
```

Example:

```sh
./diffPairs ~/outputdir ./*.html
```

Comment: `while [ $# -ge 2 ]; do ...`?

Comment: @shawn it also work with comparing arithmetically as you suggest. testing `[ "$2" ]` is true as long as `"$2"` is not empty. Works the same as `[ -n "$2" ]`.

Comment: What if it gets passed an empty string as an argument? (Not likely when dealing with filenames, of course, but in the general case...) Using the number of positional parameters is more robust.